# AWS: Make route private from outside world

Tags: web-services, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I have a web application currently running on an EC2 instance with MySQL running alongside it.

I'm building another backend batch service that needs information from the MySQL database. However, I don't want it to access the DB directly. What I want to do is build in a few API routes in the web application, i.e. `/private/foo`, `/private/bar` that are only accessible internally (e.g. within the VPC), while all other routes will continue to work as per normal.

I'm wondering how I can go about setting that up?

Comment: voting to close as "unclear what you are asking" because the question is about modifying an application but not even a high level description of this application is present in the question

Comment: The question isn't about modifying the application. I have a legacy app that's running on an EC2 with it's own DB, I need to build another service that relies on that database but I don't want the other service to have direct access to the DB, so I want to add a few more endpoints to my application.

Imagine I have /home, /app, /about, etc, as well as /private/foo and /private/bar. I was all routes accessible via the Internet, except those starting with /private. In those cases, they should only be accessible to other services running within the same VPC.

Comment: Sorry, even your comment to clarify the situation simply raises more questions.  What do you mean by "endpoint"? "build another service"?  I am guessing you are using some kind of framework - perhaps written in PHP that implements this stuff but that is *pure* supposition on my part

Comment: Yes, the PHP app is built with Drupal. The other service, in this case, would be a NodeJS service, possible running on Amazon Lambda.

An endpoint is synonymous with a route (i.e. GET /users would be an endpoint).

"Build another service" in the context of service-oriented architecture / microservices.

The reason I'm not specifying what framework the applications are built in is because it shouldn't really matter. i.e. if I were doing this at work, I would probably coordinate with ops / devops to get this happen. I would rather not implement the checks within the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run an http/s Apache reverse-proxy server in front of your web application. Use this new web-tier to control all your internal and external http/s traffic.

## External Traffic:

1. Configure Apache to listen on 80/443 for external traffic.
2. Use and configure Apache module Proxy-Pass to reverse-proxy all your web-application traffic in the Apache virtualhost configuration for port 80/443.
3. Block access to `/private` using `<Location >` directives within your 80/443 virtualhost config
4. Update your DNS records to point to this web-tier instead of your web-application

## How to accommodate your internal traffic:

1. Have Apache listen on a new port, e.g. 8080
2. Configure the Apache virtualhost for port 8080 to reverse proxy the internal http requests to your web-application, i.e. `/private`

## How to secure the design:

1. Use AWS security groups to block any external traffic on port 8080.
2. Double-down on your security rules by using Apache `allow,deny` rules within your Apache 8080 virtualhost config to ensure traffic is only permitted from your internal ip-range

### An alternative Apache config to the above:

Don't bother with port 8080, and use 80,443 for all internal and external traffic. Internal traffic would make requests against a different domain name, and your internal and external traffic can be managed/separated using Apache name-based virtual-hosting https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html

Answer (score 1):

Your VPC uses a private subnet (you are able to configure the address). All you need to do is make sure that traffic coming to your server originated from the same subnet.

Since you want the existing webapp to serve these private routes, you'll need to look for the originating IP address inside your code. (If you don't know how to do this, you might ask a new question about that.)

An alternative is to run a second service (or the same service but listen on a second port). If all private traffic comes in on port `8081` (for example) and all public traffic comes in on port `8080`, you can just use AWS's security groups to allow only subnet-local traffic to port 8081 and all traffic to 8080.

Comment: Is there no way to achieve this without having to check IP ranges within the application? i.e. at a Route53 level?

Comment: Yes, but I'm understanding what you're trying to convey by a second port. If I start the same service on a different port, how can I ensure that some routes are blocked on 8080, for example, but open on 8081 - would it involve checking the port?

Comment: E.g. use an env var `PRIVATE`. When it's true, include the private routes, when false don't. Now run your main service listening on 8080 with `PRIVATE=false` and your secondary on 8081 with `PRIVATE=true`